# Executing an SQL statement inside c# code gives error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

The code I have is pretty simple:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientData]([ClientDataID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[SessionID] [char](24) NOT NULL,[Browser] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,[IP] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,[OperatingSystem] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT [PK_SessionData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ClientDataID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ON [PRIMARY]");            
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Upon executing, I get this error:

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'*

The query is generated by MS SQL 2008 and I just copied it as it was. Could someone please tell me why this doesn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: You sure your query should end with `ON [PRIMARY] ON [PRIMARY]` ? Please read [`CREATE TABLE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

Comment: pfff my mistake...by trying to remove the carriage return characters, I mistakenly removed a closing bracket, it should be **ON [PRIMARY]) ON PRIMARY**. It works now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `ON [PRIMARY]` twice, but it should only be listed once.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script in SqlCommand.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientData]([ClientDataID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[SessionID] char NOT NULL,[Browser] varchar NOT NULL,[IP] varchar NOT NULL,[OperatingSystem] varchar NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT [PK_SessionData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ClientDataID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] )

Answer (score -2):

NOT sure whether you are looking for this!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientData]
(
[ClientDataID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) 
NOT NULL,[SessionID] [char](24) NOT NULL,
[Browser] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[IP] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[OperatingSystem] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SessionData] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ClientDataID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
)
```

Comment: Answers should explain what is wrong, not just give a solution.